# How to convert Opencv Mat to JPEG char data

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg, mat

Recently, i am having trouble with converting a Mat frame captured from my webcam by OpenCV to a normal JPEG unsigned char array. I've tried one or two way on Google but the result seems not the correct jpeg uchar array. Here is a piece of my code:

```
 VideoCapture cap(0);
 if(!cap.isOpened())
    return -1;
 Mat frame;
 cap >> frame;
 if( frame.empty()) 
    return -1;
 int size = frame.total() * frame.elemSize();
 unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[size];
 memcpy(buffer, frame.data, size * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Then i used **fwrite** to write that buffer into a **file.jpg** (it looks silly but it does work if the buffer is correct),but the file cannot be openned or be determined as a jpeg image.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: What is the nett result you actually want? Do you want a JPEG file on disk? A Mat in RAM?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the OpenCV function [`imencode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63). It will fill a buffer with data encoded as the correct image type (based on the file type argument) so that it can be written to a file and other programs will know what to do with it.

The problem with your current approach is that you are attempting to write *raw* image data as a JPEG, but JPEG is a compressed data format so programs won't know what to do with the data you've written. It would be equivalent of taking a binary file and just saving it as a JPEG, the file won't have the right headers to be decoded as an image and the data otherwise likely won't match up with the JPEG format anyways.

Comment: !!! you're totally right! i have just tested it, thank you so much for your help. omg, i have been around it for several hours.

Comment: ops, i'm sorry but the buffer after being compressed by imencode() is not what i want, which is 640*480*3,  is there any way to make the compressed buffer fills all the unsigned char array of 640*480*3?

Comment: That's not what `jpg` does. `jpg` is a lossy compression, so you almost always have less buffer size than pixel data. I think you were thinking of `bmp`.

Comment: @QuangHoang my original code took the image out by using [v4l2 linux](https://jayrambhia.com/blog/capture-v4l2), i am not so sure about how it works but the code does define output of camera is MJPEG and capture a frame into an array size 640*480*3. When i write it out with **fwrite** , it's totally fine  :(

Comment: @hoango27 I think you want a bitmap or a TIFF or a PNG, or any other lossless format. JPEG is lossy data, period. It does not store raw data.